# django - detect which apps are user-authored and not packages

Tags: django, logging

In my project, I try to enforce logging format for apps that are not imported as packages but created within project by my fellow devs (as logs from these apps can contain user-sensitive data).

For this, I created a `logging.Filter` that checks if the `LogRecord` has the name of the module and then conditionally modifies it.

For example, if this is my app list (part of it):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    # django-supplied
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',


    # third-party apps
    'webpack_loader',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_s3_storage',

    # user-created apps
    'nlp',
    'catalog',
    'broker',
]
```

then the filter checks if the `LogRecord.name` starts with any of `['nlp', 'catalog', 'broker']`.

The question is, how do I detect user-created apps without hardcoding their names into the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to hardcode it. But you can do that in your django settings file which would be explicit and maintainable.

```
# settings.py

CORE_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'webpack_loader',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_s3_storage',
]
USER_CREATED_APPS = [
    'nlp',
    'catalog',
    'broker',
]
INSTALLED_APPS = CORE_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + USER_CREATED_APPS

# customfilter.py
from django.conf import settings

if any(LogRecord.name.startswith(user_app_name) 
       for user_app_name in settings.USER_CREATED_APPS): 
    ...
```